# Problem with question 1, week 3, Introduction_to_Data_Science_in_Python coursera

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm seriously stuck with this question and have no idea what I am doing wrong.
This is the error I keep getting.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-2bd159dc8ff9> in <module>
     21     new_df = new_df[:15]
     22     return new_df
---> 23 raise NotImplementedError()

NotImplementedError:
```

I can remove the error and run the code, but the output remains wrong, I get something like[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8tCW.png) but I should get a ranked list from 1 to 15 with no repeated countries.

And this is the code I am using:

```
    Energy = pd.read_excel("assets/Energy Indicators.xls",skiprows=17,skipfooter=38,na_values=['...'])
    Energy.drop('Unnamed: 0', inplace=True, axis=1)
    Energy.drop('Unnamed: 1', inplace=True, axis=1)
    Energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
    Energy['Energy Supply']=Energy['Energy Supply']*1000000
    Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].replace({'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region':'Hong Kong',
                                              'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland':'United Kingdom',
                                              'Republic of Korea':'South Korea','United States of America':'United States'})
    Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.extract('(^[a-zA-Z\s]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
    GDP = pd.read_csv('assets/world_bank.csv',skiprows=4)
    GDP = GDP.replace(["Korea, Rep."],"South Korea")
    GDP = GDP.replace(["Iran, Islamic Rep."],"Iran")
    GDP = GDP.replace(["Hong Kong SAR, China"],"Hong Kong")
    GDP = GDP[['Country Name','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015']]
    GDP.columns = ['Country','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015']
    ScimEn = pd.read_excel('assets/scimagojr-3.xlsx')
    df = pd.merge(ScimEn,Energy,how='inner',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')
    new_df = pd.merge(df,GDP,how='inner',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')
    new_df = new_df.set_index('Country')
    new_df = new_df[:15]
    return new_df
raise NotImplementedError()
```

Any ideas about what is wrong with this code?? Would highly appreciate any help.

If helpful, this is the question:

Question 1
Load the energy data from the file assets/Energy Indicators.xls, which is a list of indicators of energy supply and renewable electricity production from the United Nations for the year 2013, and should be put into a DataFrame with the variable name of Energy.

Keep in mind that this is an Excel file, and not a comma separated values file. Also, make sure to exclude the footer and header information from the datafile. The first two columns are unneccessary, so you should get rid of them, and you should change the column labels so that the columns are:

['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable]

Convert Energy Supply to gigajoules (Note: there are 1,000,000 gigajoules in a petajoule). For all countries which have missing data (e.g. data with "...") make sure this is reflected as np.NaN values.

Rename the following list of countries (for use in later questions):

"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"

There are also several countries with numbers and/or parenthesis in their name. Be sure to remove these, e.g. 'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be 'Bolivia'. 'Switzerland17' should be 'Switzerland'.

Next, load the GDP data from the file assets/world_bank.csv, which is a csv containing countries' GDP from 1960 to 2015 from World Bank. Call this DataFrame GDP.

Make sure to skip the header, and rename the following list of countries:

"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea",
"Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
"Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"

Finally, load the Sciamgo Journal and Country Rank data for Energy Engineering and Power Technology from the file assets/scimagojr-3.xlsx, which ranks countries based on their journal contributions in the aforementioned area. Call this DataFrame ScimEn.

Join the three datasets: GDP, Energy, and ScimEn into a new dataset (using the intersection of country names). Use only the last 10 years (2006-2015) of GDP data and only the top 15 countries by Scimagojr 'Rank' (Rank 1 through 15).

The index of this DataFrame should be the name of the country, and the columns should be ['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'].

This function should return a DataFrame with 20 columns and 15 entries, and the rows of the DataFrame should be sorted by "Rank".

Comment: The code you are running ends with `raise NotImplementedError()` and it raises a `NotImplementedError`. Seems like it's working to me or we are missing an import part of the code. What result were you expecting?

Comment: remove the line: raise NotImplementedError()

Comment: Cousera has its own Discussion forums for each course. That might be a better place for this question as the people there would have more context for these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what the following means?

```
raise NotImplementedError()
```

It may help to look up Python Exceptions.

If you delete this line, it shouldn't give this error anymore. This was probably put in the code to indicate that it was not finished, so you may encounter other unexpected behaviour or error messages if that is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't know it and will read about Python Exceptions. But anyway my output for the code is wrong, and this compromises the answer to the next questions of the assignment.

Comment: Glad to help! It might' be made this way specifically to have readers trying to understand the code.

If you follow the lines of the code, do you understand what happens? If it is a course I would expect there to be preceding chapters where you can learn this.